# ¿Cómo quitar el espacio sobrante entre tabla y tabla?

Tags: array, tablas, latex, text, salto-de-linea

soy nuevo aquí.
Debo hacer un informe de laboratorio. He estado probando LaTex, desde Overleaf. Pero estoy teniendo problemas al crear tablas e insertarles imagen, pues al terminar la tabla se crea ese espacio.

Ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]